# Why does uvicorn not find my modules that are in the same folder as my main.py?

Tags: python, uvicorn

Im trying to build a fastapi python backend. My Backend Structure is basically this:

```
backend/
  src/
```

and in `backend/src/` are all of my python files (main, crud, db, models) also a **init**.py.

but when trying to run my backend via uvicorn i keep getting errors like:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crud'` aswell as a long list of different Errors like

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Users\dietz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\dietz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\dietz\Desktop\Code\ToDo\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "C:\Users\dietz\Desktop\Code\ToDo\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 467, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\dietz\Desktop\Code\ToDo\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
```

I am basically still a noob so this might be a obvious thing im missing.

I tried running the backend with a **init**.py in my src folder and also without (python 3.10)
ive tried running uvicorn with literally just uvicorn src.main:app or also like this: uvicorn src.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000.
Ive both tried VSC and Pycharm. And ive set my src folder as Sources Root.
Im also activating my venv before i run it

Comment: If you are running `uvicorn src.main:app`, then your code would need to `import src.crud` (or `import .crud`, but absolute imports are generally a better choice). `import crud` would only work if you were running uvicorn from the directory containing `main.py` and `crud.py`.

Comment: ive tried running uvicorn directly from src with the imports like "import crud" and ive also tried like you told me import src.crud from the backend folder which is the parent folder of src. Still same problem. right now im getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'" which is the 2nd import in order.

Comment: We've given you as much help as possible without seeing an [mcve] that shows us exactly how to reproduce the problem you're asking about.